# What is the Shortcut Key for the Firefox Orange Button?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

What is the Shortcut Key for the orange button at the upper left portion of the Firefox 4 window? I tried ALT+F, but this only brings up the hidden "File" menu.

Comment: Wow, did they really leave that out?

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: Not sure if it's accessible via JS? If so, you might be able to get at it via keyconfig (http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be one. You could periodically check [this question](https://support.mozilla.com/gu-IN/questions/795419) on the Mozilla forum to see if a member of the Firefox team gives any insights (why there is no shortcut, are there plans to include one, etc.).

Comment: Here's an English link: https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/795419

Comment: It's a shame that Mozilla has not given that button a special name. They just call it "Firefox". Who knows you're talking about the menu button or Firefox software itself. And it is event not suitable to call it a "button"; how can a button be place in the top left corner of the window.